# Displaying different content within a single view based on the user's role

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's assume that we have a menu within my angular SPA application, now I want the basic options to be displayed to all of the users, such as home, about us, carrier opportunities etc.

I would also like to have several other options, such as manage users, mange posts etc, that will be displayed only to an admin.

Let's also assume that we have an API access point that provides me with the user role, or better yet, that the user role is within the object that retrieved from /api/users/me.

What would be the best way to encapsulate those management tools from being viewed by regular users?.

Is there some kind of inheritance among views? like in Django?, is there any way to hide the DOM elements from the unauthorized user?(yes, I know that it's client side).

I'd really prefer not to use different views for the menu, since it's supposed to be a generic component.

I suppose that if the answer to all my previous question is no, the question that remains is: what is the best implementation for this? a custom directive("E" + "A")
say:

```
<limitedAccss admin>Edit page</limitedAccess>
 <limitedAccss user>view page</limitedAccess>
```

or perhaps just using the regular ng-show with a condition on the user object?.

Comment: If you're going down the ng-show road, consider using ng-if instead. The difference is that ng-if removes the DOM element, whereas ng-show / hide just toggles a "display: none" style. Ng-if is only available in 1.1.5, though.

Comment: what about using a custom directive as I suggested and then removing the unneeded markup in the $compile function?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not yet that familiar with the $compile function to comment on that. Also hoping to see more answers. :)

Comment: One good option would be to use ng-include directive to load the privileged templates that are accessible only to the admin. You can have a scope variable inside ng-include's src attribute which initially would be an empty string. Now once you know the role you can update the variable with the path to the template. This would dynamically load the template for you.

Comment: What if I have an SPA with different roles, lets say a a thread with comments, where a user can post and comment, and the moderator and admin can also remove and edit other's posts?, so in fact I only need 2 additional buttons for those users, not a whole template

Comment: I think that the approach depends on the app and its requirements, and a good way to handle that flexibility is by using an authorization service that can be leveraged by directives and controllers.  The service handles the auth logic, the directive and controllers just handle the UI behavior. Additional information can be viewed on this link:  http://www.ozkary.com/2016/07/angularjs-spa-directive-claims.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The solution is in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BmQuY/3/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('authService', function(){

  var user = {};
  user.role = 'guest';
  return{
    getUser: function(){
      return user;
    },
    generateRoleData: function(){
      /* this is resolved before the 
         router loads the view and model.
         It needs to return a promise. */
      /* ... */
    }
  }
});

app.directive('restrict', function(authService){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 100000,
        scope: false,
        compile:  function(element, attr, linker){
            var accessDenied = true;
            var user = authService.getUser();

            var attributes = attr.access.split(" ");
            for(var i in attributes){
                if(user.role == attributes[i]){
                    accessDenied = false;
                }
            }


            if(accessDenied){
                element.children().remove();
                element.remove();           
            }


            return function linkFn() {
                /* Optional */
            }
        }
    }
});
```

if you want to use this directive with IE 7 or 8, you'll need to remove the element's children manually, otherwise an error will be throw:

```
  angular.forEach(element.children(), function(elm){
    try{
      elm.remove();
    }
    catch(ignore){}
  });
```

Example of possible usage:

```
<div data-restrict access='superuser admin moderator'><a href='#'>Administrative options</a></div>
```

Unit test using Karma + Jasmine:
**Attention:** the `done` callback function is only available for Jasmine 2.0, if you are using 1.3, you should use [waitsFor](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html) instead.

```
  describe('restrict-remove', function(){
    var scope, compile, html, elem, authService, timeout;
    html = '<span data-restrict data-access="admin recruiter scouter"></span>';
    beforeEach(function(){
      module('myApp.directives');
      module('myApp.services');
      inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $injector){
        authService = $injector.get('authService');
        authService.setRole('guest');
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        // compile = $compile;
        timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
        elem = $compile(html)(scope);
        elem.scope().$apply();
      });
    });
    it('should allow basic role-based content discretion', function(done){
        timeout(function(){
          expect(elem).toBeUndefined(); 
          done(); //might need a longer timeout;
        }, 0);
    });
  });
  describe('restrict-keep', function(){
    var scope, compile, html, elem, authService, timeout;
    html = '<span data-restrict data-access="admin recruiter">';
    beforeEach(function(){
      module('myApp.directives');
      module('myApp.services');
      inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $injector){
        authService = $injector.get('authService');
        timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
        authService.setRole('admin');
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        elem = $compile(html)(scope);
        elem.scope().$apply();
      });
    });

    it('should allow users with sufficient priviledsges to view role-restricted content', function(done){
      timeout(function(){
        expect(elem).toBeDefined();
        expect(elem.length).toEqual(1);
        done(); //might need a longer timeout;
      }, 0)
    })
  });
```

A generic access control directive for elements, without using ng-if(only since V1.2 - currently unstable), or ng-show which doesn't actually remove the element from the DOM.

Comment: I also have a unit test for this directive, I will post it right now

Comment: Posted the unit-tests, please let me know if there is anything else I can help you with :)

Comment: @OlegTikhonov hmm...I have a similar implementation but in my case `expect(element).toBeUndefined()` fails as it is actually defined. Isn't it that in your case the test passes only 'cause you're having a `timeout(..)` around, who's function is never called??

Comment: Unfortunately, this hack does not work on newer version of Jasmine, and you need to define an async test with passing `done` a parameter to the test case, and then calling it inside of the timeout function.
I shall post an example.
Perhaps a longer timeout will be required as well.

Comment: @OlegTikhonov But does it actually run?? Because I'm not getting an undefined element when I execute it, but rather it is always defined, given you store it in the `elem` variable. The `element.remove()` only removes it from some parent element, which in this case doesn't exist. Instead I had to wrap it in the `html`, something like `'<div><span data-restrict data-access="admin recruiter scouter"></span></div>'`. In the expect I then check whether the `span` is present or not. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Tests ran for me prefectly with `angular@1.0.7` with `angular scenerio@1.0.7` `ng-mocks@1.0.7` `and Jasmine@1.3`.
Since then I suppose the APIs changed a bit, and now you have to define an async test explicitly.
Other than that I don't see a problem, but if you'll suggest an edit with a more correct assertion, I will approve it.

Comment: Why do you remove children before removing the element? Remove the element removes the entire elements tree (element and its children) from DOM, doesn't it?

Comment: This is a hack for IE, don't ask me why, but it did not work otherwise on older IE versions.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I have a question regarding this.

Comment: Shoot, go ahead

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I have a question regarding this. The problem is that this still allows administrative content to be viewed by regular users in the browser (just open up the console and look for all the elements that have "restrict admin" tags). Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: This is by far the best solution..!! Is there any better way now in '17 ??

Comment: I really like this solution, however it doesn't seem to work on elements that get repeated via `ng-repeat`, any ideas on why that might be?

Answer (score 4):

`ng-if`is definitely the way I would do it! Just put the moderation tools throughout the view where they belong and they will appear if the user should have them. `ng-show`/`ng-hide` are ok too, if you're using a version of angular previous to 1.1.5.

[Live demo! (click here)](http://jsbin.com/IhEveRA/4/edit)

It is VERY important that make sure your backend/server/api will not honor a request just because your js made a call for a moderator action!! Always have the server validate their authorization on each call.

Comment: What if the roles is an (array) object with many roles? Like roles = {'Admin', 'Members', 'Editor'}

Comment: @DavidKEgghead looks like the OP thought of that and made a directive to deal with it. I was thinking along the lines of `ng-if="userIs('admin moderator contributor')`

Comment: This approach isn't any good because it can be easily manipulated by unchecking the `display: none;` property. The button will then be visible and clicked. This requires server-side validation in any case even though this should be done anyways. I'd go with @OlegTikhonov 's aproach because this will remove all elements which shouldn't be seen by the current user role.

Comment: @LordTribual I suggested `ng-if`, so you would not be able to unhide the element. It simply wouldn't be in the DOM. The directive in Oleg's answer ought to use `ng-if` as I suggested rather than manually manipulating the DOM directly with `.remove()`. If using a version of Angular where `ng-if` isn't implemented, you could either shim it or just use `ng-show`. There's nothing to worry about if the element is just hidden rather than absent. If your server is that insecure, then anyone that knows to open the console and show the element could also just send bad requests directly to the server.

Answer (score 0):

ng-if or ng-hide are ok for this,

the html is just a view and should not be responsible for handling security , your security

Having a permissions object associated with the user can be useful.
When i retrieve user data i get a permission json then on the angular

```
<div ng-if="user.permissions.restrictedArea">Very restricted area</div>
```

And the user Json looks like this:

```
{name:"some one", permissions:{restrictedArea:false,sandbox:true}} //and so on...
```