# Spring Security vS AngularJS -> Problems when using sec:authorize tag

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

I am creating a dynamic menu, all info of the menu I am getting from mysql database.

In my 'menu' database, there's a column called "role_access", where I can manipulate the roles. My intention is to fill this column in the database for each rule I have, then using the code below I could show/hide the menus depending if the client is USER or ADMIN.

```
                <sec:authorize access="hasRole('{{roleAccess}}')">
                    <li class="menu-dropdown classic-menu-dropdown "><a
                        data-hover="megamenu-dropdown" data-close-others="true"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;"> <span
                            ng-bind="menu.nome"></span>
                    </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left">
                            <li ng-repeat="menu in menu.submenus"><a
                                href="{{menu.nomeRecurso}}"><span ng-bind="menu.nome"></span></a>
                            </li>

                        </ul></li>

                </sec:authorize>
```

But, when loading the page, Spring Life's Cycle (loads everything before) is different from AngularJS (loads everything after page is loaded).

So, when using {{roleAcess}}, AngularJS is not loading my menu. If I force this roleAccess manually without the {{}}, it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use these together like this. Spring security's tags require the server to be doing the rendering. If you want to use angular, you'll need to build the logic in to the angular app to determine what role the user is and add options accordingly. This isn't for Spring, but the concept is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043412/displaying-different-content-within-a-single-view-based-on-the-users-role

Comment: Chris, thanks for replying and for the link... in this approach could be dangerous to set the role hardcoded like the post, because I could inspect in the browser, change the value and break the code...
But I am reading again, to see if I missed sth, and looking at other posts... Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're correct. You have to make sure that your server will not blindly trust what comes from the UI but also that you're ok with the user potentially being able to see these menus/api calls. If you are not, then you should use a combination of server-side rendering and client side rendering to make sure that nothing gets sent to the client that the client shouldn't see. This approach however will make the angular code a bit more complex.

Comment: Hum, I got it. Right.
well, can I ask you something? I am actually looking for it also. Is there a way I can force this to render? AngularJS has an option to force the rendering? *I Know it would not be 'correct'

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you ask a new question with the code you're talking about that's not rendering?

Comment: Chris, please, post your comment as an answer because you are completelly correct ! I have to change the arch here.

Thanks, I'm waiting to mark as correct.