# How to use Spring Security to secure Role based web services in my AngularJS web-app?

Tags: angularjs, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am developing a web application project using Spring and Hibernate. I am using MySQL database as backend, Angular Js in the frontend
and Spring & Hibernate for the web-services.

I will host the frontend pages and service in different servers.
The web service is consumed in Angular js.

My question is will I be able to add Spring Security and session management to my project?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project exactly with this configuration of frameworks.

We migrated from jsf to jsp+angularJS, with spring and hibernate. I use mysql as my database as well.

I am facing troubles with spring security and angularjs together, when regarding roles access, see:

[Spring Security vS AngularJS -> Problems when using sec:authorize tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551694/spring-security-vs-angularjs-problems-when-using-secauthorize-tag)

But, it is being the only thing I had trouble till now, I implemented spring security.

As per spring documentation, as I remember, if your front end is calling the services, it will be possible.

Just my opinion, I would wait for others posts as well.

Good luck buddy.

=]